# A way to prevent opening dev tools in puppeteer instance

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I want to prevent opening dev tools from puppeteer's chromium instance.
Unfortunately emitted page is of 'other' type so it cannot be closed by page.close method.

Here's my question, is there any way to do it by dev protocol or anything like that?

```
browser.on('targetcreated', (target) => {
    if (target['_targetInfo']['type'] === 'other') {
        target.page().then(currPage => {
            currPage.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Heard about --disable-dev-tools flag but I think it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This is not documented but it worked for me:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--devtools-flags=disable'],
  defaultViewport: { width: 1280, height: 900 }
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://google.com');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `devtools` option in [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions) to `false` to disable Puppeteer from auto-opening a DevTools panel for each tab.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  devtools: false,
});
```

Comment: Yes but later you can open it easily, I want to disable it permanently